# Getting error while using buttonText method for selecting menu

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have an element Admin in the menu of a web page.
Below is the HTML tag of the element , got it from Firebug:

```
<button class="md-button-toggle md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-show="canShow()" ng-click="toggle()" aria-controls="side-menu-admin_short" flex="" layout="row" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="pull-left ng-binding ng-scope">Admin</div>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down md-toggle-icon ng-scope" ng-class="{'toggled' : isOpen()}" style=""></div>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></button>
```

I am using protractor to automate web application, for the above element I used buttonText method to click the element but error thrown.

```
element(by.buttonText('Admin')).click();
```

Which locator i need to use to click on the Admin?

Comment: <button class="md-button-toggle md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-show="canShow()" ng-click="toggle()" aria-controls="side-menu-admin_short" flex="" layout="row" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false">
 <div class="pull-left ng-binding ng-scope">Admin</div>
 <div aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down md-toggle-icon ng-scope" ng-class="{'toggled' : isOpen()}" style=""></div>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></button>

Comment: Above commented one is the html tag when i inspected element using firebug

Comment: Also used binding locator but still could not find element

Comment: element(by.binding('Admin')).click();  also not working

Comment: Does the `element(by.partialButtonText('Admin')).click();` works for you?

Comment: Tried with element(by.partialButtonText('Admin')).click();, but not working, still the same error is shown as explained in the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I found it easier to find by CSS. Try this out:

First let's giving the element a better class name:

`<div> class="pull-left ng-binding ng-scope prt-admin"> Admin </div>`

Now find that element by CSS class like so:

`element(by.css('.prt-admin').click();`

If you don't want to change the CSS class, try this:

`element(by.css('.pull-left ng-binding ng-scope')).click()`

or

`element(by.css('.pull-left')).click()`

Comment: I can't change the the element to have a better class name as suggested since application is already developed. I need to automated only using the existing elements with their classes.

Comment: Tried using  If you don't want to change the CSS class, try this:

element(by.css('.pull-left ng-binding ng-scope')).click()

or

element(by.css('.pull-left')).click() but the same error i have seen